# Flexible resize for position: absolute and its left?

Tags: jquery, css

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
<div class="des-main">
 <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" width="100"/>
</div>

<div class="des-sidebar-wrapper">
       <div class="des-sidebar pure-u">
             <div class="des-sidebar-section">

                    <a>Contact designer</a>

                </div>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

JQuery

```
var _sidebar = $('.des-sidebar');
    var top = _sidebar.offset().top - parseFloat(_sidebar.css('marginTop').replace(/auto/,0));

    $(window).scroll(function(){
          var y = $(window).scrollTop();

           if(y >= top){
                _sidebar.addClass('fixed');
           }
           else{
                _sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
           }
    });
```

in the des-main area, the different images will be larger or smaller depending on the uploads. So the css for the des-sidebar-wrapper's left should follow according to the des-main width. Is there a way for changing the left accordingly? Left: auto will only move sidebar to the left side at 0. So if you change the image width to 200px, the sidebar will overlap with image.

Help appreciated!

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kittymeow/YyLMa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality handles based on your image width,

Try this,

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/YyLMa/1/)

```
var _sidebar = $('img');
var position = _sidebar.width();
$( ".des-sidebar-wrapper" ).offset({ left: position+_sidebar.offset().left});

    $(window).scroll(function(){
          var y = $(window).scrollTop();

           if(y >= top){
                _sidebar.addClass('fixed');
           }
           else{
                _sidebar.removeClass('fixed');
           }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, but sidebar is not moving smoothly to left. it is like when i resize, the sidebar would jump

Comment: you need to observe - if you click run, text will be overlapping on image and after a few seconds, it will move back a few spaces away from image

Comment: @kittymeows sorry i didn't find change, try this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/YyLMa/4/

Comment: thanks for your effort, but it is still overlapping for a few seconds. Never mind.